# Add click animation to a layout in android

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout showing a menu with a few options. Is there a way to add that click animation (like the one ListView has when you tap on an element) to each element once they are tapped?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [RippleEffect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect). This is a Ripple animation from Material Design for API level 9+

Comment: Thanks sir, I'll take a look at it